# Spring Boot Mock REST API Integration Test: look for null value in JSON response

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

As part of my [JHipster-generated](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKgK_18s3XAhUS24MKHTSeBXUQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jhipster.tech%2F&usg=AOvVaw1mA3hnPCnrNwKmlSqEvmK6) Spring Boot app, I'm trying to adapt an integration test to ensure that the return JSON object contains null for a particular property:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

.andExpect(jsonPath("$.selectedChannels[0].channelValue")
    .doesNotExist())
```

This doesn't seem to work. For the response:

```
{
    "selectedChannels": [{
        "name": "test channel",
        "channelValue": null
    }]
}
```

I would get a response:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected no value at JSON path "$.selectedChannels[0].channelValue" but found: [null]
```

I suppose the "doesNotExist" call is trying to make sure that the key does not exist. I tried using "value" as well with a null value but this just throws a NPE. How do I perform this assertion successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there may be some bug that causes Spring Framework (Spring Boot version 1.5.4 currently) to render the null value as a net.minidev.json.JSONArray with a single value of null. So `"channelValue": null` is rendered to `"channelValue": [null]`. This prevents the **nullValue** matcher from working.

Currently the only solution I could muster to this problem was to implement and use my own Matcher. Using the NullValue matcher as a template I have this:

```
import org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

/**
 * Matcher that can be used to detect if a value is null or refers to an empty list,
 * or a list that contains a single null value. 
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class IsNullOrEmpty<T> extends BaseMatcher<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        System.out.println(item.getClass().getPackage());
        if(item instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray arr = ((JSONArray)item);
            return arr==null || arr.size()==0 || (arr.size()==1 && arr.get(0)==null);
        }
        return item==null;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("null or list of null");
    }

    /**
     * Detect if the value is null or contains an empty array, or an array of a single element
     * of null
     * @return
     */
    public static Matcher<Object> isNullOrEmpty() {
        return new IsNullOrEmpty<>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Path Matcher `doesNotExist()` is intented to be used to assert that no key is present. For your example the key `channelValue` is present and therefore the assertion fails. See also official Javadocs (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/JsonPathResultMatchers.html#doesNotExist--) for JsonPathResultMatchers `doesNotExist()`:

> Evaluate the JSON path expression against the response content and assert that a value does not exist at the given path.

What you want for your provided response is checking if the response contains a null value for the key `channelValue`:

```
resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$.selectedChannels[0].channelValue").value(nullValue());
```

Make sure to add a static import for Hamcrest nullValue() matcher: `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;`

Comment: I don't see a static method for `nullValue` mentioned in any of the libraries I have referenced. Can you direct me to its proper location?

Comment: It is a Hamcrest matcher with should already part of your JHipster applicatio. Import with `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;`

Comment: Ah, that particular matcher does not work: `org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.nullValue()` returns the response: Expected: null but: was <[null]>. Spring's JsonPathResultMatchers is casting null to a list of null for some reason.